# Count the number of processes during compiling code

Tags: linux, process, thread

We are using `ant` as build system that calls different other tools (`Java` tools, `Python` scripts, `Perl` scripts, `LaTeX` and so on). Now I would like to know how many processes have been created during the whole compilation run.

I'm looking for an easy to count the number of processes that have been used during the time I compile code.

Is there such a utility and how will you use it for this purpose?

Comment: If it is just you on the machine, just track starting/endign process ID number.  Otherwise something like `/usr/bin/time -v` (gives different output from plain built-in `time`) may be of interest to you

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you mean by "process".

If you mean a call of a tool, then you might either write wrapper scripts which count up some bookkeeping variable or try to find some stats tool,
like https://github.com/codehaus/antomology, or log the ant run and parse that output.

If you mean system calls you might either look for a profiling tool which keep this statistics or try a kernel trace and try to extract and count the system calls for process creation.